# Цель вывести из списка 3 случайных числа без повторений. Пишет ошибку. В чем проблема?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, shuffle

```
a =  [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
b = int(input('Сколько чисел '))
import random
a = random.shuffle(a)
qwe = len(str(a))
print(qwe)
c = 0
while qwe > 0 :
    c = a[1:b]
    del a[1:b]
    qwe -= 1
    print(c)
```

Comment: random.shuffle is deprecated since version 3.9, will be removed in version 3.11

Comment: `random.shuffle(x[, random])` ... *Deprecated since version 3.9, will be removed in version 3.11: The optional parameter random.* Не дезинформируйте людей.

Comment: Если пишет ошибку, то сначала нужно читать ошибку, и только потом уже обращаться за помощью.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = random.shuffle(a)
```

Смотрим описание функции `random.shuffle`:

> Shuffle list x in place, and return None.

Не нужно присваивать результат работы этой функции обратно в список, список и без этого будет отсортирован "на месте", а вот в результате такого присваивания в переменной `a` окажется `None` и именно из-за этого дальше по коду возникнет ошибка:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Что вы делаете в вашем коде дальше я не очень понимаю, но ошибка у вас возникает из-за вышеописанной ситуации. Нужно вызывать `shuffle` без присваивания обратно в переменную:

```
random.shuffle(a)
```